# Why the HttpServlet class is an abstract?

Tags: java, servlets

I am very confused. Why the HttpServlet class is an abstract? And what is the basic difference between bean and pojo?

Comment: Heading and body content are different!?!?!

Comment: ???... r u confused...or making us confusing ?`

Comment: I've moved the title to your question body. In future, always include the question in the body. Else you might not get a good response.

Comment: So, why do you think the class shouldn't be `abstract`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909206/why-httpservlet-is-an-abstract-class-any-functional-reason

Comment: Your bean/pojo question is an entirely different question, and should be asked in a different post (if at all).

Comment: Would you ever need instance of `HttpServlet`? How would you use it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742533/why-httpservlet-class-is-declared-as-abstract for the first question

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans for the pojo/bean question

Answer (score 2):

HttpServlet is abstract because it's completely useless without concrete implementations of the business methods. The javadoc says:

> Provides an abstract class to be subclassed to create an HTTP servlet
>   suitable for a Web site. A subclass of HttpServlet must override at 
>   least one method, usually one of these:
>
> - doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
> - doPost, for HTTP POST requests
> - doPut, for HTTP PUT requests
> - doDelete for HTTP DELETE requests
> - init and destroy, to manage resources that are held for the life of the servlet
> - getServletInfo, which the servlet uses to provide information about itself

Bean and Pojo are terms that usually refer to simple java classes that do not implement interfaces or extend classes from external libraries/frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Why would `HttpServlet` *not* be abstract? An instance of *just* `HttpServlet` would be useless - the whole point of a servlet is to be able to provide useful responses to requests, and `HttpServlet` can't do that. It's generally a good idea to prevent useless situations where possible.

As another example of something similar, consider [`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html). That's abstract despite having no abstract methods, because it's useless until you override *at least one* method.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [API](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

> Provides an abstract class to be subclassed to create an HTTP servlet
>   suitable for a Web site. A subclass of HttpServlet must override at
>   least one method, usually one of these:
>
> - doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
> - doPost, for HTTP POST requests
> - doPut, for HTTP PUT requests
> - doDelete, for HTTP DELETE requests
> - init and destroy, to manage resources that are held for the life of    the servlet
> - getServletInfo, which the servlet uses to provide information about    itself

HttpServlet does not have useful functionality on its own.

Comment: thank you for your response.But my question is "if there is no any abstract method present in HTTP servlet class(means we have to override all methods) then why it is called ABSTRACT class?"